# Getting "Cannot open user default database. Login failed." for connections that don't specify a default database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have two virtual machines. Server A is running SQL Server 2000. Server B is running SQL Server 2008R2. I am using the same domain user to log in to both boxes.

But I cannot log in to SQL Server locally on server A. I get `Cannot open user default database. Login failed.` when attempting with Query Analyzer or Enterprise Manager.

I can connect from server B using SSMS if I specify a database to connect to.

Once thus in, I have tried changing the default database for my user to 'master' via the GUI and via `exec sp_defaultdb 'DOMAIN\username', 'master'` but it does not change things. I have tried setting other databases as the default and verified that those databases are queryable by me. No luck. Unless I open a connection with SSMS and specify a database, the login fails.

This login problem is also preventing me from running linked queries against server A. How can I get this fixed?

Answer (score 1):

That error either means that the default database does not exist or that it is not accessible to the user. Try to set tempdb as the default and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `Cannot open user default database.` error has the following causes:

1. The login does not have access to the database.  This can have one or more of the following causes:

   - Permissions haven't been appropriately assigned to the user linked to the login.
   - The login has not been mapped to a user in the target database.
2. The database is in one of the following conditions:

   - offline
   - no longer exists
   - is suspect
   - is in emergency status
   - has been detached
   - is inaccessible due to being a mirror if Database Mirroring is enabled, or is part of an Availability Group where read-only access has not been configured.  (this doesn't apply to SQL Server 2000, but is common enough that I'm leaving it here for folks who may see this question based on errors they are having in newer versions of the product).
   - The database may be in `SINGLE_USER` mode, and another user has already connected to it.
   - The database has been set to `RESTRICTED_USER` mode, and the login is not a member of the database `db_owner` role, or is not a member of the `sysadmin` server-level-role.

Ensure the login mentioned in the error message exists at the server level<sup>1</sup> using the following query:

```
SELECT sp.[name]
FROM [sys].[server_prinicpals] sp
WHERE sp.[name] = N'<login_from_error_message>';
```

Ensure a user is properly linked to the database:

```
USE [<database-name>];
GO

SELECT [user_name] = dp.[name]
FROM [sys].[database_principals] dp
    INNER JOIN [sys].[server_principals] sp ON dp.[sid] = dp.[sid]
WHERE sp.[name] = N'<login_from_error_message>';
```

If the above query returns no results, you may need to create a user in the database:

```
USE [<database-name>];
GO
CREATE USER [<user_name>]
FOR LOGIN [<login_name>]
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo];
GO
```

Ensure the *user* has permission to connect to the database:

```
GRANT CONNECT ON DATABASE::<database_name> TO <user_name>;
```

---

<sup>1 - if you're using contained databases, there may be other issues in play</sup>